# React-native: index.js: Transformer.transform is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native. After upgrading react-native from 0.48.3 to 0.62.2 on a project I get the error when running "react-native run-ios" command: "index.js: Transformer.transform is not a function".
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/948JL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is my solution:

- If you are running npx react-native start, just stop it.
- Run npm outdated
- Updated in package.json the Wanted versions. Her is my configuration: `"devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.11.1", "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2", "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0", "babel-jest": "^25.5.1", "eslint": "^6.8.0", "jest": "^25.5.4", "metro": "^0.61.0", "metro-core": "^0.61.0", "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0", "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"   }`
- Then delete the node_modudes folder
- Run npm install
- Run npx react-native start
- Run npx react-native run-ios in new terminal.

Comment: Not Working don't try this